# NDSolve with two parameters

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I was trying to solve a ODE numerically. It has two parameters (`w` and `z0`) which I want to vary. The following code gives an error: "Cannot find starting value for the variable".

```
g[z_] := 1 + 3 ( (z/z0))^4 - 4 ( (z/z0))^3 
DE = x''[z] + D[g[z]/z^2, z]/(g[z]/z^2) x'[z] +  (w^2)/(g[z])^2 x[z] == 0;

a = 10^-4;
zb = 0.0001;

pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
            DE, x'[z0 - a] == - I (z0 w)/(6 w^2) x[z0 - a], x[zb] == 1
           }, x'[zb], {z, zb, z0 - a}, {w, z0}]
Plot[Evaluate[Table[
          Re[pfun[w, z0]]
    , {z0, 0.5, 1, .1}]]
    , {w,-0.01,0.01}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: This error is an "Initial Condition" definition error. Please consider rewriting `x'[z0 - a] == - I (z0 w)/(6 w^2) x[z0 - a], x[zb] == 1` in a more clear way.

Comment: @SerhanAya Thanks for your comment! But I have no idea how to modify it. Can you suggest something which might work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be caused by the boundary condition evaluated at a variable point. As an illustration, this

```
y[4][3] /. ParametricNDSolve[{
              y''[x] + y'[x] + y[x] == 0, 
              y'[10] == y[10], 
              y[0] == u
           }, y, {x, 0, 10}, u]
```

will evaluate just fine, but changing the `y'` initial condition to

```
y[4][3] /. ParametricNDSolve[{
              y''[x] + y'[x] + y[x] == 0, 
              y'[u] == y[u], 
              y[0] == u
           }, y, {x, 0, 10}, u]
```

will return the error

```
ParametricNDSolve::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable y'.
```

In your case, of course, you've got your boundary conditions and that's that, and you can't really change them without changing your problem. What you can do is either

- move away from `ParametricNDSolve` as a solver, in favour of functionalized constructs such as

  ```
  f[u_?NumericQ] := f[u] = y /. First[NDSolve[{
                                         y''[x] + y'[x] + y[x] == 0,
                                         y'[u] == y[u], 
                                         y[0] == u
                                        }, y, {x, 0, 10}]]
  ```

  which evaluates `f[4][3]` just fine, or
- re-scale your problem to a new independent variable `ζ` with a fixed range, such as `ζ=z/(z0-a-zb)`, for which this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I have some very basic doubts. 
Why the "First" is so crucial here? Also if I have two such parameter how to plot the function as I did in my question?

Comment: The `First` is because `NDSolve` returns its results as a list of lists of replacement rules (as a parallel to `DSolve`, which can return multiple independent solutions, cf. the output of `DSolve[y'[x] + x y'[x]^2 == 1, y, x]`), as opposed to `ParametricNDSolve`, which returns a simple list of replacement rules. If you have more than one parameter simply use `f[u_?NumericQ,v_?NumericQ] := f[u,v] = (whatever)`. For more on `_?NumericQ`, see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037).

Comment: Got it now. Another quick confusion : 
`Plot[Table[f[u][x],{u,1,10}],{x,0,10}]` gives back all curves but with same color. Any way out how to get different colors for different curves?

Comment: Wrap the `Table` inside an `Evaluate`. This will force the `Table` to evaluate to an explicit list, which the `Plot` command then recognizes as things that need to be plotted in different styles. It's admittedly a bit of a bizarre idiom.

Comment: In my original question if I use the following code (following your suggestion), it doesn't give me the output. I must be making some silly mistake here! 

`f[w_?NumericQ, z0_?NumericQ] := f[w, z0] = x /. First[NDSolve[{DE, x'[z0-a] == -I (z0 w)/(6 a^2) x[z0-a], x[zb] == 1},x ,{z,zb,z0-a}]]` 

`f[0.001, 2][zb]`

Comment: Always test with a specific value before you run with it. Try `Block[{w = 0.001, z0 = 2},  NDSolve[{DE, x'[z0 - a] == -I (z0 w)/(6 a^2) x[z0 - a], x[zb] == 1}, x, {z, zb, z0 - a}]  ]`. It returns the error `NDSolve::bvluc: The equations derived from the boundary conditions are numerically ill-conditioned. The boundary conditions may not be sufficient to uniquely define a solution`. This is a fundamental problem with your equation and you need to address it directly; there's little that we can do to help without knowing what it is you're working on.